# Merge List of custom classes by property

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of a custom class workdate:

```
class workdate
{
  string dayid;
  List<string> blocks;
}

Workdates.Add(new workdate("1", {"a","b","c"});
Workdates.Add(new workdate("2", {"a","b"});
Workdates.Add(new workdate("1", {"d","e","f"});
```

How can I use linq to merge the list items based on the same **dayid**:

"1", {"a","b","c","d","e","f"}

"2", {"a","b"}

Comment: So what form do you want the results in? A new `List<workdate>`? (Btw, you should really follow .NET naming conventions, even in small demo apps...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Workdates.GroupBy(x => x.dayid)
         .Select(g => new workdate 
                      { 
                          dayid = g.Key, 
                          blocks = g.SelectMany(x => x.blocks).ToList()
                      }).ToList())
```